Tracking where an DITL resource is called within a 68k program
Okay, so I'm a super noob at reverse-engineering and know next to nothing about 68k assembly code. I'm running an emulated version of MacOS 9.0.4, using a program called Resorcerer 2.4.1 to examine my program of choice. I've located a pop-up window in the DITL resources that I'm interested in and I want to track down where it's called. How would I do so?
Or, if you don't want to bother answering my stupidly vague question, could you direct me to a place where I can learn to do this?

Try searching the disassembled code for the 4cc 'DITL'. There will be some Toolbox calls. I'm not a classic Mac expert but I know resources are treated as 32-bit values and not as strings. I don't know if Resorcerer disassembles the m68k code or not but there are some projects on GitHub that can.
